# HTML List wont center

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/pfW2v/39/

```
<ul style="text-align: center;list-style-type: none;margin: 1;padding: 0;display:inline-block;">
<li style="list-style-position:inside;font: 200 18px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;border-bottom: 6px solid #00ff09;width: 80px;">
    <a href="a">TopDave25</a> 1000</li>
<li style="font: 200 15px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;border-bottom: 6px solid #00a806;width: 80px;">
    <a href="b">Masterchief36</a> 400</li>
<li style="font: 200 10px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;border-bottom: 6px solid #0d6b1d;width: 120px;">
    <a href="#">Your Username!</a>
</li>
```

Above is a link showing my list, i have to use inline HTML (Cant use a CSS stylesheet or `<style>` in the HTML but using `text-align: center;` does nothing, I have tried googling and it just doesnt seem to want to center

Comment: 'Above is a link showing my list'
its in the link

Comment: It's in the link, not in the question. Make it easy for us to help you by not making us go elsewhere to see your code. **Include it in the question.** Better still use the <> button in the editor to include a snippet in the the question. It is just like jsfiddle but on StackOverflow itself.

Comment: And why do you have to use inline styles and not a style section or stylesheet?

Comment: I cannot in this instance use either <style> or a css page. the reason for this is irrelevant, its just my current predicament.

Comment: It may be relevant, is this for an HTML email? In which case the results may vary from client to client.

Comment: No, its not specified because it wont change the results, I can use any HTML that works inline, that is it.

Answer (score 5):

Place it inside a div:

```
div
{
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Individual Widths from the li's and add a width say around 100px to ul..

It should solve your prob.

Working Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/pfW2v/40/

Comment: They're not centered there though D:

Comment: OKay well when I remove the width and then set center in the ul above, it makes the border width huge again, and if i try and set width in ul it doesnt center

Comment: You want Topdave25 and 1000 to be in one line &&  MasterChief36 and 400 in next...

Do you want like this..?

Comment: Yes next to each other, centered, and the border thing just being a snug like 100px

Comment: You want length of border under only Text or 
equal length for all the elements as per the longest li length.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

```
<div id="maindiv">
<ul style="text-align: center;list-style-type: none;margin: 1;padding: 0;display:inline-block;">

<!-- ALL CODE INSIDE DIV -->

</ul>
</div>
```

In css:

```
#maindiv{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed in JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pankaj_Ladhar/pfW2v/44/

I have added `style="display:block"` for anchor make it come in next line. If you don't want remove this code form `<a>` tag.

I have also added `width:250px` to `<ul>` to make `li` should look center aligned. You can remove that as we all.

Comment: i appreciate the effort but i mean I nee dthe whole list centered

Comment: Do u need mean centre in screen ? If yes add one container give width and margin : 0 auto